# comparing two pdf and save output to pdf in diffpdf on cmd windows

Tags: php, cmd

The two PDF files that I wanted to compare and stored in a remote server 
The following is my command-line arguments:

```
diffpdf --output-diff="\\SERVER_PATH\Output.pdf" "\\SERVER_PATH\PdfFile1.pdf" "\\SERVER_PATH\PdfFile2.pdf"
```

but it is not working...!
Is any other way to do this?

Please any one help.
advance thanks for your help

Comment: Is there any error message? If yes, please edit your question.

Comment: no error,it is display the compare output,but not save as pdf

Comment: eventually you can redirect the output to the output file.

Comment: `command .... >output.file`